# MongoDB subdocument query to limit elements

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Here's what my document looks like.

```
{
    ID: "XYZ",
    messages: [
        {
            ID: "AAA",
            text: "this is a message"
        },
        {
            ID: "BBB",
            text: "this is a message"
        },
        {
            ID: "CCC",
            text: "this is a message"
        },
        {
            ID: "DDD",
            text: "this is a message"
        },
        {
            ID: "EEE",
            text: "this is a message"
        },
        {
            ID: "FFF",
            text: "this is a message"
        },
        {
            ID: "GGG",
            text: "this is a message"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to aggregate and get messages for example from `CCC` to `FFF`

```
{
    ID: "XYZ",
    messages: [
        {
            ID: "CCC",
            text: "this is a message"
        },
        {
            ID: "DDD",
            text: "this is a message"
        },
        {
            ID: "EEE",
            text: "this is a message"
        },
        {
            ID: "FFF",
            text: "this is a message"
        }

    ]
}
```

So how is this possible?

Comment: Try using `$unwind`, `$match`, and then `$group` in your pipeline.

Comment: I already did, that's not enough for this problem

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using the $slice operator.
[Check out the mongodb documentation on $slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/).
Run your query to get the document and use the slice operator with the query:

```
query.slice('messages', [numOfElementsToSkip, numOfElementsToReturn]);
```

Or more specific to your request:

```
query.slice('messages', [2, 4]); // Return 4 elements after skipping 2
```